# erasing element from std::vector <int*>

Tags: c++, pointers

Can we expect the following code work always without giving any error?

```
int a=1, b=1, c=1;

std::vector <int*> edges;
edges.resize(3);

edges[0] = new int;
edges[0] = &a;

edges[1] = new int;
edges[1] = &b;

edges[2] = new int;
edges[2] = &c;

delete edges[0];
edges[0] = NULL;
edges.erase(edges.begin());

delete edges[0];
edges[0] = NULL;
edges.erase(edges.begin());

delete edges[0];
edges[0] = NULL;
edges.erase(edges.begin());
```

Comment: No, it is totally broken. You are leaking memory, and calling `delete` on things that shouldn't be deleted. I would not expect it to ever work, but undefined behaviour can sometimes look like it is working.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Then how should I erase a specific pointer from the container?

Comment: Erasing is the least of your worries. It is worth taking a step back and figuring out what pointers are, and what dynamic allocation is. There are plenty of questions on this, and introducory C++ books *might* cover it. Introductory C books should definitely cover it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see where you're going, but you've fallen into a common trap for people who learned Java or C# before C++:

```
int a=1, b=1, c=1;

std::vector <int*> edges;
edges.resize(3);

edges[0] = new int;  // this line is unnecessary
edges[0] = &a;
```

The call to `new int` allocates memory for an `int`, and stores the address in `edges[0]`.  But the very next line decides to point `edges[0]` to the address of `a`.  The memory allocated by `new int` is leaked.

What's more, the call to `delete edges[0]` is effectively a call to `delete &a`, which is not what you want at all (you can only `delete` `nullptr` or things you got from `new`; and you did not get `a` from `new`).

Unlike Java or C#, `new` actually means something in C++.

The calls to `edges.erase(edges.begin())` are all good, though.

So, edited, this would work:

```
std::vector <int*> edges;
edges.resize(3);

edges[0] = new int(1);
...
delete edges[0];
edges.erase(edges.begin());
```

But I have to wonder why you aren't using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`, which will take care of the memory management for you:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> edges;
edges.resize(3);
edges[0] = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)); // or edges[0] = std::make_unique(1); in C++14
...

edges.erase(edges.begin());
...
```

In fact, if `int` isn't a stand-in for some other type (i.e., you actually want a container of `int`s), you should just use `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> edges;
edges.resize(3);
edges[0] = 1;
edges[1] = 2;
edges[2] = 3;

edges.erase(edges.begin());
edges.erase(edges.begin());
edges.erase(edges.begin());
```

Comment: I like "`new` actually means something in C++". It reminded me of [a question I once asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340535/is-the-new-keyword-in-java-redundant).